# Accessing join query results in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

If I have:

```
query = db.session.query(Food, Person).filter(Food.id == Person.favourite_food)
for row in db.session.execute(query)
    print row
```

The output for first print I get is:

```
(1, u'Alice', 25, u'F', u'z', None, False, 1, u'icecream', 1, None, False)
(5, u'Bob', 38, u'M', u'z', None, False, 3, u'pizza', 1, None, False)
```

How do I do:

```
print row.name, row.gender # <-- how do I do this?
```

The result does not seem to have column names anymore.

Edit: And also is there a way to serialise the query results with just one line, something like

```
return Response(json.dumps(query.results), mimetype='application/json')
```

Answer (score 8):

When you specify

```
    query(Food, Person)
```

the resultant rows will be of type sqlalchemy.util._collections.result, 
and it will have two fields: Food and Person

the Food part can be referenced either by row[0] or row.Food
the Person part can be referenced either by row[1] or row.Person

so e.g.

```
    print(row.Person.name, row.Person.gender) # works
    print(row[1].name, row[1].gender) # also works
```

if you only wanted particular fields, you could specify them in the query, eg:

```
    query = (db.session.query(Person.name, Person.gender, Food.name.label('foodname'))
             .filter(Food.id == Person.favourite_food))
```

and then the object will have 3 fields: name, gender, foodname

```
    print(row.name, row.gender, row.foodname)
```

Comment: Man I have been looking for this for ages. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can execute your query differently:

```
for row in query.all():
    print row[1].name, row[1].gender
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to serialise the query results with just one line, something like return Response(json.dumps(query.results), mimetype='application/json')

Comment: You mean: `answer = [(row[1].name, row[1].gender) for row in query.all()]`